# TinyURL API Blocking URL Domain

Tags: deep-linking, tinyurl

I am subscribing to TinyURL API to shorten our URLs. However, as of this morning, TinyURL API generating links for our URLs with error code 422 and error message "URL domain banned."  Does anyone have any idea about what I can do to fix this?

I tried to create TinyURL link for other URLs such as "www.stackoverflow.com" and that worked. It seems that only my internal URLs are being blocked. Everything was working fine until this morning.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [we literally cannot help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577). Contact their support folks.